# python upset plot data type unclear

Tags: python, visualization, venn-diagram, upsetplot

I am trying to make an **upset plot** using gene-disease association lists. I assume that I simply do not understand which data type is required as an input as most examples use artificially created datasets that are of the data type "int64".

Upsetplot: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/upsetplot/latest/upsetplot.pdf and https://pydigger.com/pypi/UpSetPlot

I copied the examples given in the links above and they work just fine. When I try my own dataset I get the **error message**: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

The data I use as input is a **data frame** with boolean information (see attachment "mydata.png" [mydata boolean df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kUcD.png)). So I have the diseases as columns, the genes as rows and then boolean statements about the specific gene being associated with that disease or not (I can make this sound more computational if required).
An example data set that works can be found in the documentation or in the screenshot "upsetplot_data_example.png" [upsetplot_data_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIcAE.png). In the documentation is says something about "category membership", but I do not quite understand what data type that is.

I assume it is a basic issue of not understanding what "format" is required. If anyone has an idea of what I need to do, please let me know. I welcome all feedback. I do not expect anyone to actually do the coding for me, however some pointers would be so helpful.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The recently released [Data Format Guide](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html) might prove helpful. Perhaps you need to set those boolean columns as the index of your data frame before passing it in, although ultimately, it may be easier to use [`from_contents`](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#upsetplot.from_contents) or [`from_memberships`](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#upsetplot.from_memberships) to describe your data.

However, upsetplot [will hopefully make the input format easier in a future version](https://github.com/jnothman/UpSetPlot/pull/75).